# Trigonmetric sum of inverses

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, summation

> Prove that:
>   $$\sum^{45}_{k=1}\frac{1}{\cos1^\circ-\cos(87+4k)^\circ}=\frac{1}{2\sin 1^\circ}$$

Numerically, this is accurate comparing the [lhs](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=summation&a=*C.summation-_*Calculator.dflt-&f2=1%2F%28cos%28pi%2F180%29-cos%28%2891%2B4k%29*pi%2F180%29%29&f=Sum.sumfunction%5Cu005f1%2F%28cos%28pi%2F180%29-cos%28%2891%2B4k%29*pi%2F180%29%29&f3=0&f=Sum.sumlowerlimit%5Cu005f0&f4=44&f=Sum.sumupperlimit2_44&a=*FVarOpt.1-_**-.***Sum.sumvariable---.*--) and [rhs](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F%282sin%281%C2%B0%29%29).
Some ideas: We can transform the question into proving that:

$$\sum^{45}_{k=1}\frac{1}{\sin(43+2k)^\circ\sin(44+2k)^\circ}=\frac{1}{\sin 1^\circ}$$
Since clearly every term is positive, there is no hope in trying to cancel terms. I have also tried to transform this into a sum of inverses of roots of an equation so that I can use Vieta's formulae, but I have had no success.

Comment: Where did the "$n$" come from?

Comment: @EdwardJiang Sorry, it was a $1$.Edited!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

$$\sin1^\circ=\sin[(44+2k)^\circ-(43+2k)^\circ]$$
$$=\sin(44+2k)^\circ\cos(43+2k)^\circ-\cos(44+2k)^\circ\sin(43+2k)^\circ$$

$$\implies\frac{\sin1^\circ}{\sin(44+2k)^\circ\sin(43+2k)^\circ}=\cot(43+2k)^\circ-\cot(44+2k)^\circ$$